# new version of protoc-gen-go drops already known types

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

There are two .proto files

**1st file | name "a.proto"**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package a;

message AMsg{
    fixed64 smth1 = 1;
    fixed64 smth2 = 2;
}
```

**2nd file | name "b.proto"**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package b;

import "a.proto";

message BMsg {
    a.AMsg msg1 = 1;
    a.AMsg msg2 = 2;
}
```

previous versions of protoc-gen-go generated the following code:

**file "a.pb.go"**

```
package b

import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
import fmt "fmt"
import math "math"    

. . .  

type AMsg struct {
    smth1 uint64 
    smth2 uint64 
}

. . .
```

**file "b.pb.go"**

```
package b

import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
import fmt "fmt"
import math "math"   
import "a"

. . .  

type BMsg struct {
    msg1 *a.AMsg
    msg2 *a.AMsg
}

. . .
```

and everything was alright,

**but**

one day a new version of protoc-gen-go had come

and **file "b.pb.go"** now looks like this:

```
package b

import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
import fmt "fmt"
import math "math"   

. . .  

type BMsg struct {
    msg1 *AMsg
    msg2 *AMsg
}

. . .
```

you can notice that already known types are dropped here, but i can't find out the reason. (i. e. prefix "a." i missing)

this [link https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated) says nothing about the new approach

**What should I do to make protoc-gen-go to generate "b.pb.go" without these drops?**

Comment: What do you mean by "well known types"?

Comment: @Adrian maybe i uset incorrerct note, it may be called already-known type. So a message that is declared in other proto file and is imported in the current.

Comment: They only need to be imported if they're in different packages. Are they in different packages? Does the generated code not compile? What problem are you actually having?

Comment: @Adrian before protoc-gen-go update import of messages from different packages worked quite good, but after update , import fails , and generated code doesen't compile. so in "b.bp.go" before update fields of a struct were *a.AMsg, and after update  they look like *AMsg . Thats the problem

Comment: If the generated code doesn't compile, that's a bug in protoc - try updating to the latest version or open an issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`go_package` option solved this, you should explicitly specify the package in `a.proto`

like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package a;
option go_package= "some_path/A";

message AMsg{
    fixed64 smth1 = 1;
    fixed64 smth2 = 2;
}
```

so you will get right generated types from `a.proto` in other proto files